# CMFCTabCtrl get handle of tabs and their childs

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a properly initialized object of CMFCTabCtrl in my application.
I have added some tabs to it by

```
m_oMTC.AddTab(pTab, Name, -1, FALSE);
```

now I want to iterate over over all tabs in m_oMTC, get tabs handle and check some of it's child item. How can i do this?

I used this code for iterating

```
int nTabCnt = m_oMTC->GetTabsNum();
for (int i = 0; i < nTabCnt; i++)
{
    m_oMTC->SetActiveTab(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CMCFTabCtrl* is derived from [CMFCBaseTabCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983503.aspx).  You should be using [CMFCBaseTabCtrl::GetTabWnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984143.aspx) to iterate through the child tabs within your loop.  Depending on how you've set up the tabs, you may need to enumerate the child CWnds on the returned CWnd from `GetTabWnd`.